# Select records where sum of assigned quantity in one table not matches with total quantity in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables 'orders' and 'assigned_orders'. When I create an order it get entered in orders table with certain quantity. I assign this orders to different vendors with some quantity. so let say in orders table I've 500 quantity in total where I'm assigning 300 quantity to vendor 'A' and 100 quantity to vendor 'B'. Now, I'm left with 100 quantity unassigned.
Now I want to get a record from orders and assigned_orders table which will show like:

Orders

| id | customer_name | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cust 1 | 500 |
| 2 | cust 2 | 700 |

assigned_orders

| id | order_id | assigned_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 300 |
| 2 | 1 | 100 |

Expected result

| id | order_id | quantity | assigned_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 500 | 400 |

Comment: GROUP BY, SUM() then JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

use join and aggregation

```
   select o.id,ao.order_id,
     sum(ao.assigned_quantity) as assigned_quantity,
     sum(o.quantity) as quantity
    from assigned_orders ao join
     Orders o on o.id=ao.order_id
    group by o.order_id,o.id
```

Comment: ran the query but it is showing me an error message - Unknown column ao.assigned_quantity in field list. If I remove it from select, it shows me the result set without the assigned_quantity

Comment: @KamleshGhate, the query is correct, check this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=84178f076545416f850083864d783e0d

Comment: Yes this is correct, it was my mistake. Thanks @Zaynul